# Stop on second click of the button

Tags: java, android

I have button with for inside his onclik. i Want stop 'for'or hide button with stopping method but i'm not able to do this. 
I have tried with while and variable++ but it don't work with visability gone but it was hiding after 'for' completed.

```
public void siema(View view) {
for(i=2;i<5; i++){
some if's 
}}
```

and what my problem is : if i click button 5 times it goes 5 times i want to block it or make method siema stop on second click of the button.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: Post your code with proper explanation

Answer (score 0):

use this code that would help you

```
int count=1;


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

    if(count>1)
    {
    //do action
    }else{
    count++;
    }
                }
            });
```

this will help you.